# Text are not centered vertically in large screens

Tags: android

I would like to make the text in "Status" text view centered horizontally and vertically. It works in HTC ONE X+ but not in Samsung Tab S and Huawei Honor 6 Plus such larger screen. How can I make the text centered in all screen?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ServiceUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Task"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Status"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/Status"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ServiceUser"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ServiceUser"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/ServiceUser"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/ServiceUser"
    android:layout_below="@id/ServiceUser"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Remark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/Task"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/Task"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/Task"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/Task"
    android:layout_below="@id/Task"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/Status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/Task"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/Time"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is what I get when putting it into the renderer, http://ibin.co/2Aox6sRot0Zi. I don't see how it would be centered on any device. Can you explain what the overall layout should look like?

Comment: @JacobPhillips I mean status would be center vertically in the right column as the image you post. It is now on the top which like on the same row with serviceUser and Task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to use nested LinearLayouts in this case. The outermost one here could be omitted but gives you a place for the main content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ServiceUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:text="ServiceUser" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:text="Time" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Task"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:text="Task" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Remark"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:text="Remark" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Status"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Status" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- More content here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This will look like the image I posted above on any screen.